# Consolidating array data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a JSON array from an api which has the structure like this:

```
newArray = [
{
 "item":{"id":1, "name":"item1"},
 "type": [1,2,3]
},
{
"item":{"id":2, "name":"item2"},
"type": [4,5]
},
{
"item":{"id":3, "name":"item3"},
"type": [8,9]
},
{
"item":{"id":1, "name":"item1"},
"type": [11,12]
},
{
"item":{"id":2, "name":"item3"},
"type": [31,41]
},
{
"item":{"id":3, "name":"item3"},
"type": [11,23]
}
]
```

I want to return an array with objects having same `name` and `id` in a single object.

```
resultArray = [
{
"item":{"id":1, "name":"item1"}, 
"type": [1,2,3,11,12]
},
{
"item":{"id":2, "name":"item2"},
"type": [4,5,31,41]
},
{
"item":{"id":3, "name":"item3"},
"type": [8,9,11,23]
}]
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.reduce()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a single loop proposal with [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and a helper object for the reference to an inserted item.

```js
var newArray = [{ "item": { "id": 1, "name": "item1" }, "type": [1, 2, 3] }, { "item": { "id": 2, "name": "item2" }, "type": [4, 5] }, { "item": { "id": 3, "name": "item3" }, "type": [8, 9] }, { "item": { "id": 1, "name": "item1" }, "type": [11, 12] }, { "item": { "id": 2, "name": "item3" }, "type": [31, 41] }, { "item": { "id": 3, "name": "item3" }, "type": [11, 23] }],
    resultArray = [];

newArray.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.item.id]) {
        this[a.item.id] = { item: a.item, type: [] };
        resultArray.push(this[a.item.id]);
    }
    this[a.item.id].type = this[a.item.id].type.concat(a.type);
}, Object.create(null));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(resultArray, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

As i have mentioned in the comment, since the output is a reduced version of the input `Array.prototype.reduce()` is cut out for this job and results a very simple "chainable" code. So if you add construct to Array prototype and slightly modify, you can do like `newArray.construct(e => somecode with e).filter(e => somecode with e ).map(e => somecode with e)` This is essential for functional programming. Check it out

```js
var newArray = [
{
 "item":{"id":1, "name":"item1"},
 "type": [1,2,3]
},
{
"item":{"id":2, "name":"item2"},
"type": [4,5]
},
{
"item":{"id":3, "name":"item3"},
"type": [8,9]
},
{
"item":{"id":1, "name":"item1"},
"type": [11,12]
},
{
"item":{"id":2, "name":"item3"},
"type": [31,41]
},
{
"item":{"id":3, "name":"item3"},
"type": [11,23]
}
];

function construct(a){
  return a.reduce((p,c) => {var i = p.findIndex(e => e.item.id == c.item.id);
                            !!~i ? p[i].type = p[i].type.concat(c.type) : p.push(c); return p}, []);
}
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(construct(newArray),null,4) + "</pre>");
```